# Detecting UIScrollView Motion

Tags: uiscrollview

My UIScrollView is moving using this code:

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
```

And it will trigger

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Multiple times, and that OK. However, I am seeking a way to query the scroll view and know whether it has reached its' final station, or it is still in motion. Is there a way to do that? `isTracking` and `decelerating` are returning `NO`.

Thank you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your controller conforms to `<UIScrollViewDelegate>`...

and implement:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

From Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619379-scrollviewdidendscrollinganimati?language=objc):

> **Discussion**
>
> The scroll view calls this method at the end of its implementations of the `setContentOffset(_:animated:)` and `scrollRectToVisible(_:animated:)` methods, but only if animations are requested.

add a BOOL property:

```
@property (assign, readwrite) BOOL bIsScrolling;
```

then you can do this:

```
self.bIsScrolling = YES;
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
```

and this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"done scrolling");
    self.bIsScrolling = NO;
}
```

and elsewhere you can check `if (bIsScrolling) ...`